# PHP - Unable to create a xml file

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

**Hello everyone,**

Below is a piece of code I've been struggling to make it work lately. Unfortunately it's not working as I would like it to.

The below code is supposed to look into a "gallery" folder , find any files and folders in it and  store all the output into a xml file.

I expect the xml file would look like this..

```
<categories>
<movies>
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
</movies>
<games>
file1.jpg
</games>
</categories>
```

and so on...

But my code below is returning me this output instead:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <Categories/>
> ```

here is the code

```
<?php
    class XML_file
    {
        private $doc;
        private $root;
        private $MyXml_file_handler;
        private $node;
        private $child;

        public function __construct($root_name, $file)
        {
            $this->MyXml_file_handler = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file); //implicitly creates file

            $this->doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
            $this->node = new DOMText;
            $this->doc->formatOutput = true;
            $this->root = $this->doc->createElement($root_name);
            $this->root = $this->doc->appendChild($this->root);
            echo __CLASS__," has been created. <br />";
        }

        public function __destruct() 
        {
            fwrite($this->MyXml_file_handler, $this->doc->saveXML());
            fclose($this->MyXml_file_handler);
            echo __CLASS__," has been destroyed. <br />";
        }

        public function AppendChild($name)
        {
            $this->child = $this->doc->createElement($name);
            $this->child = $this->node->appendChild($this->child);
        }

        public function CreateNode($content)
        {
            $this->node = $this->doc->createTextNode($content);
            $this->node = $this->root->appendChild($this->node);
        }
    }

    class ImageDb
    {   
        ////// Constructor & Destructor //////////////////
        private $myXML;

        public function __construct($dir)
        {
            $this->myXML = new XML_file("Categories","myImageDB.xml");
            $this->SearchDir($dir);
            echo __CLASS__," has been created. <br />";
        }

        public function __destruct() 
        {
            echo __CLASS__," has been destroyed. <br />";
        }
        ////// Constructor & Destructor //////////////////

        function SearchDir ($dir)
        {
            if($dh  = opendir($dir))
            {
                while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) 
                {$files[] = $filename;}
                rsort($files);

                foreach ($files as $key => $value) 
                {
                    if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
                    {
                        if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
                        {
                            $this->myXML->AppendChild($value);
                            echo "Directory: $value <br />";
                            $this->SearchDir("$dir$value"); 
                        }else {
                            $this->myXML->CreateNode($value);
                            echo "File: $value <br />";
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir($dh); 
            }
        }
    }

    $image = new ImageDb("../galeria/");
?>
```

I can't really figure out where's the problem.

I'm sure that it does find all the files in that folder,  and it also prints all the 
content on the screen, but it's not working when I try to store the content to a xml file.

///////// EDIT /////

I have now amended the two functions inside the XML_file class and it's returning this.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>     <Categories>filex.txt<Space/><Nature/><Movies/>file2.txtfile1.txt<Games/></Categories>
> ```

```
public function AppendChild($name)
{
    $this->child = $this->doc->createElement($name);
    $this->child = $this->root->appendChild($this->child);
}

public function CreateNode($content)
{
    $this->node = $this->doc->createTextNode($content);
    $this->node = $this->root->appendChild($this->node);`
}
```

As you can see, it's now only printing the "closing" elements .
So now I just need to understand as to why it's not adding the "opening" elements .

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I have played arround with the **AppendChild** functions and it turned out that they were wrong.

Now the output is way better, although I'm still getting the  ending attributes when  there is no TextNode assigned to it.

```
public function AppendChild($name)
        {
            $this->child = $this->doc->createElement($name);
            $this->child = $this->root->appendChild($this->child);
        }

        public function CreateNode($content)
        {
            $tmp = $this->doc->createElement("path");
            $this->child->appendChild($tmp);

            $textNode = $this->doc->createTextNode($content);
            $tmp->appendChild($textNode);
        }
```